# Plot 3D probability distribution with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, 3d, probability-density

I have a 1024x1024x1024 matrix which resembles a 3D-space each cell corresponds to a point in space. Each element of this matrix has a value determines the probability of the presence of the particle in that coordinate.

I want to plot a three dimensional probability distribution with matplotlib. I do this with imshow in 2D but I do not know how to make it in 3D.

Thanks

Comment: If you are wanting volume rendering, or pretty iso-contours, you may wish to use mayavi. Do you know what kind of representation you're after?

Comment: `matplotlib` cannot do proper 3D plotting. It is incredibly unlikely you will be able to produce what you want with it. As @mdurant says, [`mayavi`](http://mayavi.sourceforge.net/) would be a *much* better library to use. Also, plotting a 3D voxel representation of your data will not really be of any use, data wise, it will only make something that looks pretty (if that's what you're after).

Comment: Thanks @mdurant, mayavi cloud potentially solve my problem still have to play around with it.

Comment: Feel free to post questions if you have problems; mayavi is great, but nowhere near as well documented as it should be. You'll start with the simpler mlab interface: e.g., `source = mlab.pipeline.scalar_field(data)`; `mlab.pipeline.volume(source)`.

Comment: @Yousof: I find Your description unclear. Can You post the sample data? Say first 10 points of You 1024 data samples.

Answer (score 0):

Probably You want points3d of MayaVi:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python2

import numpy as np
from mayavi import mlab

x, y, z, value = np.random.random((4, 40))
mlab.points3d(x, y, z, value)

mlab.show() # or
# mlab.savefig("1.png", size=(1000,800))
```

Result:

[image]